# What is the advantage of dual microphones?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, recording

The new MacBook Air (Jun 2013) comes with dual microphones. What's the advantage over single microphone? Anything to do with background noise cancellation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The signals from the two microphones are used, in conjunction with the Mac's built-in digital signal processing software, to cancel background noise for a person speaking into the microphones, for use in webcame programs like Messages and Skype. The signal thus generated is monaural; the two microphones cannot be used for stereo recording.

Comment: I would think the noise canceling is more for things like dictation and Siri, where clean sound is a plus.