# How to disable ambient noise reduction?

Tags: macos, audio

It used to be in that one could disable the ambient noise reduction in the sound preferences.  But I can't seem to find that option anymore, which means when I record sound with the built-in mic I have to accept the warbling effect.

According to Help, the option should be there so long as there isn't a 4-channel built-in microphone format chosen in Audio MIDI setup.  But my internal microphone is a 2-channel according to Audio MIDI Setup.

How can I get the check box to appear so that I can cancel the noise reduction effect? I have a Late 2013 27" iMac

Comment: Which model of Mac are you using? Notebook Mac? iMac? Dual microphones in newer Macs may be the cause of the missing checkbox.  [This page at AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93655/what-is-the-advantage-of-dual-microphones) may hold a clue

Comment: @icondaemon I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

This model of iMac (Late 2013, 27") has [dual internal microphones](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP688?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), which were designed to offer better noise cancellation. This is most likely why the Ambient Noise Reduction checkbox is missing.

Comment: Is there anyway to disable it through, e.g. plist modifications?  The ANR is *awful*

Comment: I don't think you'l be able to disable it, but I have no proof.